# How is it that any API that forces you to catch an unchecked exception is broken

Tags: java, exception

[Kevin Bourrillion](https://stackoverflow.com/users/202214/kevin-bourrillion) mentions [here](https://github.com/google/guava/issues/1913)-

> any API that forces you to catch an unchecked exception is already
>   broken.

How is that so?

If there is an external system that I am going to consume through a web service interface, and if it throws a SOAP Fault Exception at runtime- What does Kevin's above statement holds in this regard?

Comment: This is an "opinion-based" question if there ever was one. Have a read through [Checked exceptions: Java’s biggest mistake](http://literatejava.com/exceptions/checked-exceptions-javas-biggest-mistake/) or dozens of similar articles throughout the years. Many people believe that checked exceptions are broken, so that would contradict Kevin's assertion.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt - 1) Someone's belief doesn't contradict anything.  It is still just a belief, not a fact. Even if a lot of people believe it.  2) In fact, if anything, the (hypothetical) API design tends to invalidate the belief ... in that we have an example of where it is (apparently) *necessary* to always deal with a specific exception.  Hence a justification for having checked exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

Because Java has a feature for indicating that users of an API must catch an exception: **checked** exceptions. If an API designer is requiring you to catch an exception but it is  not a checked exception, they are not using the power of the language, and replacing something that the compiler can check with convention and commentary (which can be overlooked).